# Setting up Perfect on Ubuntu

Tags: swift, ubuntu, perfect

I'm tring to setup Perfect server on my ubuntu and I'm stuck at part when I have to clone & build PerfectLib

According to this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/server-side-swift-with-perfect/#toc_4) I should do

```
git clone https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect.git
cd Perfect/PerfectLib
make
sudo make install
```

But there isn't such directory `Perfect/PerfectLib`. I can find only `Perfect/Sources/PerfectLib` and if I run `make` then error `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

I'm not sure how I should approach it.

Answer (score 1):

So the thing is that you have cloned the version from master branch. 
(which is only compatible with Swift 3.0 March 24 Snapshot at this moment *[Apr 25 2016]*, you can't find the PerfectLib(now it is just Perfect) folder because repository structure has been modified in order to comply with Swift Package Manager)

You can clone from [release-1.0](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect/tree/release-1.0) branch and follow the tutorial.

Alternatively if you want to leverage Swift Package Manager and easily deploy on Ubuntu, you can go with Swift 3.0. But you need to install Swift 3.0 toolchain to be able to use it in xCode. [Swift.org](https://swift.org/download/#releases)
(Also you would need to clone both PerfectServer, Perfect repositories and put it together into single xCode workspace for it to pick up the dependencies)

Please also refer to my [Building Perfect Server on Ubuntu (April 28, 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36833531/2380455) answer for information on how you can build PerfectLib with Swift Package Manager on Ubuntu.

Comment: Well I'll be writing my backend in Swift 3.0, so I think I have to use second option. I've alredy installed Swift 3.0 on Ubuntu. I'm guessing there is no tuts for how to install new Perfect?

Comment: Not sure there is something, I guess they guys are busy rolling out the full SPM support now, likely they will write new guides a bit later. But I have Swift 3.0 Perfect setup in both xCode and Ubuntu. I have integrated all dependencies through PerfectServer SPM's Package.swift, so everything builds on Ubuntu with a single make. Give me some time to edit this answer, something like 12-20 hours, alright?

Also you can ask questions directly to PerfectLib team at https://gitter.im/PerfectlySoft/Perfect

Comment: That will be much appreciated :)

Comment: @Dudi: Updated the answer, take a look.